# How to exclude folders from being deleted using a for loop in a Batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10, file-handling

I am trying to delete everything in a user defined location with exception on one pre-defined folder using a for loop. How do I go about adding a exception in order to not delete a folder.

I am trying to learn how to code, but I admit I am doing baby steps. I got some excellent tips for the first input part of this script, but I lack the knowledge to move forward. I have searched and found similar code, but none seems to work. This script is intended for flight simulation and hopefully ease the workload of installing a particular item.

This is just the part of the code due to stackoverflow guidelines, it deletes everything including the folder I want to exclude. 
...

```
Rem This code is intended to delete all except one pre-defined folder
Echo Deleting all the files except testmappe3
del /s /q "%CD%"
for /d %%p in ("%CD%") do rmdir "%%p" except "%%testmappe3" /s /q 
dir
Pause
...
```

I expected the output to delete all folders except testfolder3

Comment: Try running `help for`.  There is no except clause.  Also consider `help if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would be a **very** careful deleting everything using `%cd%` especially if the script can accidently be run as Administrator, where `%cd%` would then be `c:\windows\system32`.

Instead, use `%~dp0` as path to ensure that you are in the correct directory. This all assumes you did not `cd` somewhere else earlier in the script.

Then to the actual issue, I would include findstr to exclude your directory `testmappe3 as well as your script itself.

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
for /f %%p in ('dir /b ^| findstr /vi /r /c:^testmappe3$') do (
    rmdir "%%p" /s /q >nul 2>&1
    if not "%%p"=="%~nx0" del /s /q "%%p" >nul 2>&1
)
```

If you want to stick to your original delete method, then it would be as below, but if your script is in the same dir, then it will also be deleted:

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
del /s /q *
for /f %%p in ('dir /b ^| findstr /vi /r /c:^testmappe3$') do (
    rmdir "%%p" /s /q >nul 2>&1
)
```

If your folder to exclude contains spaces, double quotes are required.. i.e

```
dir /b ^| findstr /vi /r /c:^"test mappe3"$
```

Comment: Thank you for this helpful tip, and explaination.

Answer (score 4):

```
for /d %%A in ("%CD%\*") do (
    set "except="
    if /i "%%~nxA" == "testmappe3" set "except=1"
    if not defined except rmdir /s /q "%%~A"
)
```

This code will iterate the folders in the current directory.
If the **n**ame+e**x**tension of the folder is `testmappe3`,
then `except` will be set as `1` i.e. defined with a value.
If except is not defined, `rmdir` will remove the folder.

You can add more `if` lines for checking folders to except.

The modifiers will recognize a folder such as named
`testmappe3.test1` as **n**ame `testmappe3` and
e**x**tension of `.test1`.

View `for /?` and `call /?` about modifiers.

View `for /?`, `set /?`, `if /?` and `rmdir /?` for
help with those commands.

Comment: Thank you for this added explaination, I accept this too :)